# Simple grouped product

Tags: product, bundle

I'm very interested in finding a way to create a very simple grouped product.  This is mostly like a simple product, but is made up of multiple simple products for inventory tracking purposes.

Unfortunately, neither Magento configurable products or bundles work the way I would like.  One problem is quantities of items are editable, and the other reason is the order shows a list of subproducts rather than a single product being purchased.

As I mentioned, the reason I want this to be a bundle of simple products is a) for inventory tracking, and b) shipping calculations.  Other than that I want the customer to think they are buying a single product rather than see a list of individual products on their order.

Anyone aware of any extensions that support this?

Comment: Does anyone understand and share this need?   This is a way to sell individual products or predefined bundles of those simple products (not really kitting like cameras or computers where there are customer options).

This would be truly a new product in the catalog from the customers perspective, but on the backend I'd like the inventory and shipping calculations to leverage the individual products.

Answer (score 1):

I do understand your need quite well. We've struggled with how to create these types of products for a long time. Finally got fed up and built our own Product Type. Worked so well, we made an extension out of it: http://goo.gl/76dWD5

We kept wondering why this was never addressed in Magento before, or by anyone else, really. It's such a basic product need for many businesses.

Comment: looks like a valid solution to this question.
Maybe also add screenshots how the extension looks in cart and order mails

Comment: Woudl be nice if there was a live demo site to see the back-end of this extension.

Comment: Does the extension allow the 'package product' to calculate the price as a % off of the compoenent products?   Or, even better, a % off of each item in the 'package'.   I would also like it to display the customer's savings vs. buying the individual products.

Comment: We are working on a demo video and some more screenshots. Thanks for the suggestions.

At this time, you cannot set the price as %, only as a price for the complete package. Good idea, though, and one we'll put on the board for an upcoming version.